# Fatal error comp.h not found Netbean 8.0

Tags: c++, c, macos, netbeans

I know this is not the new issues, and i had do all the research check you any possible solution match my problem. Unfortunately, i couldn't found any.

Im using Mac Yosemite 10.10, Netbean 8.0 compiling an cpp project code. I notice my issues was during compiling the system will look for omp.h at

> /usr/local/Cellar/libiomp/20150401/include/libiomp/omp.h

However, error was show the omp.h not found

```
In file included from <built-in>:339:
In file included from <command line>:4:
./predict_common.h:25:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include <omp.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/build_vocabolary.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Note: This also some warning (yellow underline) at the code that #include  not found.

My previous solutions was
1) Copy the omp.h file to `/usr/include/`  .since i notice the Netbeans was looking header files at this location. So at programming code, yellow underline was gone.

However, during compilation, system found both omp.h in different location and shown cogflict errors.

2) Remind omp.h file at `/usr/include/` and remove the one at `/usr/local/Cellar/libiomp/20150401/include/libiomp/omp.h`

Funny was, during half way of compiling, system show error omp.h file not found at 
`/usr/local/Cellar/libiomp/20150401/include/libiomp/omp.h` location!

I was wonder do I miss out to set PATH? what should i do and any setting need to me done in Netbeans ? Please assist..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solutions

Right click at Projectname -> Propertise -> C compiler 
at 
1) Include Directories -> add

```
/usr/local/Cellar/libiomp/20150401/include/libiomp/
```

*Note: at terminal check where is omp.h located by

```
$locate omp.h
```

Although it listed more than one location, but you should identify when you install clang-omp where might same location. 
2) Include Header ->

```
omp.h
```

For the above solutions, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In project properties under Build -> C Compiler  edit the include directories textfield and add the directory containing that header file.

You should delete the extra copy you put in /usr/include to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have added this /usr/local/Cellar/libiomp/20150401/include/libiomp/ link at and finally works for me.